# On the linear combination of $\pm 1$ random variables

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, fourier-transform

Let $X_1,\dots, X_n$ be i.i.d symmetric $\pm 1$ random variables, i.e. $X_j$ takes values in $\{-1,1\}$ with
$$\mathbb{P}(X_j=1)=\mathbb{P}(X_j=-1)=\frac{1}{2}.$$
Let $a_1,\dots,a_n\in\mathbb{Z}$, define
$$X=\sum_{j=1}^n a_jX_j.$$
How can we prove that
$$\mathbb{P}(X=0)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\prod_{j=1}^n\cos(a_jt)dt.\quad(*)$$

I noticed that the integrant in the right hand side of $(*)$ is the characteristic function of the random variable $X$, so I am thinking about using the inverse formula:
$$\frac{\mathbb{P}(X=a)+\mathbb{P}(X=b)}{2}+\mathbb{P}(a<X<b)=\lim_{T\to\infty}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-T}^T\frac{e^{-ita}-e^{-itb}}{it}\varphi_X(t)dt$$
where $\varphi_X(t)$ is the characteristic function of $X$. However I didn't see the connection between the inverse formula and the result we want to prove. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you have some typos in your inversion formula. Have you tried plugging in $a=b=0$ into your inversion formula? Then $P(0<X<0)$ vanishes and the rest should follow.

Comment: Sure the $a_j$s are not integers?

Comment: @AlexR.It supposed to mean that $a<b$.

Comment: @Did I think so. What would be problematic if $a_j$s are not integers?

Comment: That $(\ast)$ would become wrong, to begin with.

Comment: Ach so... finally! Now that every $a_j$ is an integer, $X$ is integer valued hence one can use the identity $$2\pi P(X=0)=\int_0^{2\pi}E(e^{itX})dt=\int_0^{2\pi}\prod_jE(e^{ita_jX_j})dt=\ldots$$ Can you end this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write $\cos(a_j t) = (\exp(i a_j t) + \exp(-i a_j t))/2$, and expand the product.  We get

$$ 2^{-n} \sum_{x \in \{-1,1\}^n} \exp \left( i \sum_{j=1}^n x_j a_j t\right) $$
Now note that $$\dfrac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \exp(ikt)\; dt = \cases{0 & if $k$ is a nonzero integer\cr 1 & if $k = 0$\cr}$$
Thus, assuming the $a_j$ are all integers, your right side becomes $ 2^{-n}$ times the number of $x \in \{-1,1\}^n$ such that $\sum_j x_j a_j = 0$, and this is $\mathbb P(X=0)$.

Well, you don't **quite** need the $a_j$ to all be integers: what you need is 
$\sum_j x_j a_j$ to always be an integer.  You could have an even number of half-odd-integers and the rest integers.